# hidden symbol `__aeabi_uidivmod' final link failed: Bad value

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, cross-platform

I have three C files *a.c, b.c* and *d.c*, compiling as below:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -fPIC  -Iab/inc/  -I../inc  ab/src/a.c -oa.o

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -fPIC  -Iab/inc/  -I../inc  ab/src/b.c -ob.o

arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -fPIC -shared a.o b.o -olibab.so

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Iab/inc/ -I../inc/ -L.  ab/test/src/d.c -L. -lab
```

If not cross compile I don't have an error or warning but, in cross compile I get error:

**Error as below**

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: a.out: hidden symbol `__aeabi_uidivmod' in gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/libgcc.a(_udivsi3.o) is referenced by DSO 
arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Problem is because of linking with **linker**(ld), If I link through gcc then this error is not seen.

linker doesn't link against libgcc.a due to which this error is seen this was response from linaro IRC channel